# Difference between ほど and まで?

Tags: word-choice, words

Both seem to indicate an extent of something, but how do they specifically differ?

Comment: What does your dictionary say for each, and what have you found so far?

Comment: As sun-solar-arrow says, I think まで　means "until" or "up to". E.g. 5時から6時まで. "From five to six [a'clock]". I've seen ほど explained as describing an "extent" of something. E.g. "イギリスには五年ほど住んでいました." I've lived in England to the extent of 5 years". But I don't see how these differ, because they seem to me to be interchangeable in those examples.

Comment: Ah I see so you're talking about something like 「驚く**ほど**似ている」「死ぬ**ほど**心配する」「そんなに**まで**私のことを心配して～～」「病気になる**まで/ほど**必死で勉強する」ほど/まで as "to the extent ~~" (btw the ほど in 五年ほど住んでいました means "about", "I lived in uk for about 5 years")

Comment: 極微妙な、あるいは実在しない差異かもしれませんが、「病気になるまで必死で勉強する」は"study hard until one falls ill"; 「病気になるほど必死に勉強する」は"study so hard that one falls ill"という感じを受けますね。/「死ぬほど愛してる」は"I love you to death" (degree or intensity); 「死ぬまで愛してる」は"I love you till I die" (temporal extent) ですね。/ I think まで is mainly used to indicate spatial or temporal extent and, to a limited extent, degree, level or intensity while ほど is never used as a "spatial or temporal extent" indicator.

Comment: As to goldbrick's distinction, I have seen "寝る時間がないほど忙しい。" [note this is a non-native speaker's usage, so it might be wrong]. However if it is right, wouldn't this be a level of intensity or 'amount of business' that would make まで more appropriate? See this article where I originally got the definition: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/amount

Comment: @chocolate Could you help me with those sentences? I'm not quite understanding the point you're making.

Comment: I just meant to say: So you're talking about まで・ほど in the sense of "to the extent (that~~)", not "until" or "approximately".

Comment: Oh that's what we're talking about, yes. I'm trying to understand how these words differ in that meaning. Isn't until similar to "to the extent"? Maybe this is me not understanding my native language here, haha.

Answer (score 1):

〜ほど means "about", "approximately". Similar to 〜くらい.
〜まで means "until", "by", "till", "reach(まで[届]{とど}く)", "(from something) to something".

<sup>from (something) to (something) means 〜から〜まで</sup>

### Examples

> - それの長さは10メートルほど(=くらい)ある。
>
>   - Its length is approximately ten meters.
> - 駅に3時までに着く。
>
>   - I arrive at the station by three o'clock.
> - 僕は5時まで学校にいるね。
>
>   - I'll stay in school until five o'clock.
> - それはここまである。
>
>   - It reaches here.